# Вылетает программа на python при запуске через python и при компиляции в exe, хотя при запуске в pycharm работает

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pyinstaller, exe

Вот демонстрация проблемы: https://youtu.be/0ALaK65O44o У меня есть ещё 4 подобных программы, с ними тоже самое, так что думаю дело не в коде, но всё же
вот код:

```
import pygame
import random
import cv2
import sys

# Инициализация Pygame
pygame.init()

# Размеры окна
screen_width = 1920
screen_height = 1080

# Создание окна
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Magic Ball")

# Изображение фона
background_image = pygame.image.load("ball_bg.png").convert()

# Изображение кнопки закрытия
exit_button_image = pygame.image.load("ball_exit_button.png").convert_alpha()
exit_button_image = pygame.transform.scale(exit_button_image, (275, 155))
exit_button_rect = exit_button_image.get_rect(topleft=(15, 15))

# Изображения для кнопки "Получить ответ"
answer_button_images = [
    pygame.image.load("ball_answer_1.png").convert_alpha(),
    pygame.image.load("ball_answer_2.png").convert_alpha(),
    pygame.image.load("ball_answer_3.png").convert_alpha()
]

answer_button_images = [pygame.transform.scale(image, (800, 180)) for image in answer_button_images]

answer_button_rect = answer_button_images[0].get_rect(topleft=(560, 650))
answer_button_state = 0  # 0 - обычное состояние, 1 - наведена мышь, 2 - нажата кнопка
answer_button_pressed = False  # Флаг нажатия кнопки

# Путь к видеофайлам
video_files = [
    "ball_yes.mp4",
    "ball_no.mp4",
    "ball_maybe.mp4",
    "ball_probably_yes.mp4",
    "ball_probably_no.mp4",
    "ball_idk.mp4",
    "ball_50_50.mp4",
    "ball_ask_again.mp4"
]

# Область, при нажатии в которой проигрывается видео
change_background_rect = pygame.Rect(707, 108, 503, 503)

# Флаг для отслеживания проигрывания видео
playing_video = False
current_video = None

# Параметры поля для ввода текста
input_rect = pygame.Rect(200, 855, 1520, 180)
input_color_inactive = pygame.Color(148, 0, 211)
input_color_active = pygame.Color(255, 0, 255)
input_disabled_color = pygame.Color(50, 0, 50)
input_text_color = (255, 0, 255)
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 90)
max_chars = 60
input_text = ''
input_active = False  # Флаг активности поля
input_disabled = False  # Флаг для отслеживания, нужно ли заблокировать поле после проигрывания видео
reset_text_after_video = False  # Флаг для сброса текста после окончания видео
enter_pressed_time = 0  # Время нажатия Enter
backspace_pressed_time = 0  # Время нажатия Backspace

# Основной цикл программы
running = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print(f"Mouse Clicked at ({x}, {y})")
            if exit_button_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                running = False  # Закрыть программу
            elif change_background_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                # Остановка текущего видео
                if playing_video:
                    playing_video = False
                    current_video.release()

                # Выбор случайного видео
                video_file = random.choice(video_files)
                current_video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
                playing_video = True
                input_disabled = False
                reset_text_after_video = False
            elif answer_button_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                answer_button_pressed = True
                answer_button_state = 2  # Нажата кнопка
                # При нажатии кнопки поле остается активным
            elif input_rect.collidepoint(x, y):
                input_active = True  # При клике поле остается активным

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            answer_button_pressed = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                # При нажатии Enter
                input_active = False  # Убираем активность поля
                enter_pressed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                # При нажатии Backspace
                if input_active:
                    input_text = input_text[:-1]
                    backspace_pressed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
            else:
                # При вводе текста
                if input_active and len(input_text) < max_chars:
                    input_text += event.unicode

    # Проверка состояния новой кнопки при наведении мыши
    if answer_button_rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
        answer_button_state = 1  # Наведена мышь
        if answer_button_pressed:
            answer_button_state = 2  # Нажата кнопка
            # Остановка текущего видео
            if playing_video:
                playing_video = False
                current_video.release()

            # Выбор случайного видео
            video_file = random.choice(video_files)
            current_video = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file)
            playing_video = True
            # input_text = ''  # Стираем текст при выборе ответа
            # input_active = False  # Убираем активность поля
            reset_text_after_video = True  # Устанавливаем флаг сброса текста после окончания видео
    else:
        answer_button_state = 0  # Обычное состояние

    # Отрисовка фона
    screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))

    # Обработка воспроизведения видео
    if playing_video:
        ret, frame = current_video.read()
        if ret:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            frame = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(frame.swapaxes(0, 1))
            screen.blit(frame, (0, 0))
        else:
            # Воспроизведение завершено, возвращаем обычный фон
            playing_video = False
            current_video.release()
            if reset_text_after_video:
                input_text = ''  # Сбрасываем текст только при установленном флаге
                reset_text_after_video = False  # Сброс текста выполнен, сбрасываем флаг
                input_disabled = True  # Возвращаем активность полю после окончания проигрывания видео

    # Отрисовка кнопок
    screen.blit(exit_button_image, exit_button_rect)
    screen.blit(answer_button_images[answer_button_state], answer_button_rect)

    # Отрисовка поля для ввода текста
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, input_color_active if input_active else input_disabled_color if input_disabled else input_color_inactive, input_rect, 2)

    # Ограничение ширины текста
    input_text_surface = font.render(input_text, True, input_text_color if input_active else (255, 255, 255) if input_disabled else input_disabled_color)
    input_text_width, input_text_height = input_text_surface.get_size()
    if input_text_width > input_rect.width - 10:
        input_text = input_text[:-1]

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if current_time - enter_pressed_time > 200:
            input_text = input_text[:-1]

    # Если Backspace зажат, текст стирается без остановки
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_BACKSPACE]:
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if current_time - backspace_pressed_time > 50:
            input_text = input_text[:-1]

    # Отрисовка текста с учетом цвета
    if len(input_text) >= max_chars:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), input_rect, 2)
        input_text_color = (255, 0, 0)
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, input_color_active if input_active else input_disabled_color if input_disabled else input_color_inactive, input_rect, 2)
        input_text_color = (255, 0, 255)

    text_surface = font.render(input_text if input_active else "Введите ваш вопрос: ", True, input_text_color if input_active else (255, 255, 255) if input_disabled else input_disabled_color)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=input_rect.center)
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

    # Обновление экрана
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Установка FPS
    clock.tick(30)

# Завершение Pygame
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Похоже, что при запуске через python рабочей директорией выбирается `C:\Windows\system32`. Добавьте к каждому пути путь к папке скрипта `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))`.

Comment: В случае с exe почитайте как правильно использовать добавленные ресурсы в pyinstaller.

Comment: IOKFO. а что с вашим предыдущим вопросом?